# Throw error message on kendo upload after wrong columns in aspx

Tags: asp.net, excel, kendo-ui, upload

I am using kendo upload to upload a file to my  server and write the data to db

```
$('#files').kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: 'test.aspx/ImportExcel'
    },
    dropZone: '.drop-zone',
    multiple: true,
    clear: function () {

    },
    complete: function(){
     //This is called when all files are uploaded
    },
```

In back-end aspx i read the excel save it to a datatable and i want to check if the datatable has 3 columns its ok and write the columns in the database else throw a message to the user that the excel is not in the correct format..How can i do this?

if dt.columns.count =3
{ write to database }
else
{ return error to user that the excel is not in correct format  };

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a "server side validation" for your uploaded file and a Panel to show a message. In the old asp.net webforms world it should looks like this:

```
     <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" EnableCustomValidation="true" ID="RadAsyncUpload1" OnFileUploaded="RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded"  >
     </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>

      <asp:Panel ID="InvalidFiles" Visible="false" runat="server" CssClass="qsf-error">
           <h3>Validation Erros:</h3>
           <ul class="qsf-list ruError" runat="server" id="InValidFilesList">
              <li>
                  <p class="ruErrorMessage">Your Excel is not valid...</p>
              </li>
           </ul>
      </asp:Panel>

     public void RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
      {
          var liItem = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
          liItem.InnerText = "Your uploaded Excel does not look so nice";
          InValidFilesList.Controls.AddAt(0, liItem);
          e.IsValid = false;  // (Add validation (see comment bellow))
      }
```

To validate your Excel file you can use [Open XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet) to check your excel file.